# jQuery Mobile toggle icon on opening and closing sidebar panel

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to toggle the icon between the hamburger menu image and a cross image when the sidebar menu panel (with the id of **#nav**) is opened (which gets the class of "**.ui-panel-opened**") and closed(which gets the class of "**.ui-panel-closed**"). The icon (which has the class of ".header-menu-icon") will be the hamburger (**icon-menu.svg**) when the sidebar menu panel is closed, and swap to the cross icon (**icon-close.svg**)by changing the image the source when the sidebar menu panel is opened.
Below is my code, however not succeeded to achieve the attempt. Comments and suggestions are much appreciated.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

        if($('#nav').hasClass('ui-panel-open')){
            $( ".header-menu-icon" ).attr("src", 'images/icon-close.svg');
        } else if($('#nav').hasClass('ui-panel-closed')){
            $( ".header-menu-icon" ).attr("src", 'images/icon-menu.svg');
        }

    });
```

Comment: What is triggering this? I would bind it to the opening of the panel event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQM panel widget exposes events for open and close

http://api.jquerymobile.com/panel/#event-close

http://api.jquerymobile.com/panel/#event-open

You can handle these events and update your button accordingly:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate","#page1", function(){ 

    $("#nav").on( "panelopen", function( event, ui ) {
        $( ".header-menu-icon").removeClass("ui-icon-bars").addClass("ui-icon-delete");
    });

    $("#nav").on( "panelclose", function( event, ui ) {
        $( ".header-menu-icon").removeClass("ui-icon-delete").addClass("ui-icon-bars");
    });

});

<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="panel" id="nav"></div>    
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>My page</h1> 
         <a  href="#nav" class="header-menu-icon ui-btn ui-icon-bars ui-btn-icon-notext "></a>
    </div>  
    <div role="main" class="ui-content"></div> 
</div>
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/rkbn59cb/)**

If you prefer to change an image:

> **[Image DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/rkbn59cb/1/)**